# What is the type of VPN created in Sharing?

Tags: vpn

I need to select either one of the following VPNs in Samsung Galaxy Tab 8.9:

1. PPTP VPN
2. L2TP VPN
3. L2TP/IPSec PSK VPN
4. L2TP/IPSec CRT VPN

**So which one should I select to access my iMac where I shared my screen for my tablet?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am 99.9% sure that the choice is Door #3 (Door #4 is the other).